# Good examples of object-oriented vs. procedural design

Tags: oop, procedural-programming

I keep reading that object-oriented programming can basically be done in any programming language, and that in order to do so, explicit language support is not required. I.e. one can write object-oriented programs in, say, plain C.

What good examples of OO design using a procedural language are there, apart from GTK+?

Which open source projects are good examples of procedural design, on the other hand? (preferably C)

Comment: One possible example if you want to read useful C code is libraries built for C, like sockets.h(http://www.stanford.edu/~stinson/cs155/bin/socket_h.txt). It'll be written in a  procedural manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, OO programming usually takes the form of calling particular initialization and cleanup functions on struct pointers, and for polymorphism, passing around structs of function pointers. One example I can think of offhand is KVM.

Comment: KVM == Kernel-based Virtual Machine?

Comment: Yes, it's a kernel module for Linux that implements hardware virtualization.